Find the measure of the smallest angle formed by the extensions of $AB$ and $CO$ in a triangle $ABC$.
In a triangle $ABC$, draw the cevian $BN$, such that $AB=CN$, the perpendicular bisectors of $BN$ and $AC$ intersect at $"O"$. If $∡⁢⁢=20°$.
Calculate the measure of the smallest angle formed by the extensions of $AB$ and $CO$. (Answer:$60^o)
I made a figure:
$AO = OC \implies \angle OAC \cong \angle OCA = 20^o $
$ \angle AOC = 180^o -2(20^o) = 140^o $
$ \angle AOP = 180^o - 140^o = 40^o $
$\angle OAB \cong \angle ABO = \theta \implies \angle AOB = 180^o -2\theta$
$\angle AEC = 180^o - (20^o +20^o +\theta) = 140^o -\theta $
$ \therefore \angle OEB = 40^o +\theta$
How do I finish?


Since $O$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $AC$, we have $|OA|=|OC|$.
Since $O$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $BN$, we have $|OB|=|ON|$.
We are also given $|AB|=|CN|$. With these three equalities, we deduce $\triangle OAB \cong \triangle OCN$. This gives $\angle OAB = \angle OCN = 20^\circ$.
We finally notice that the smaller angle between the lines $AB$ and $CO$ equals the sum of the three angles $\angle OAC , \angle OCA , \angle OAB$. This sum is $20^\circ + 20^\circ + 20^\circ = \boxed{60^\circ}$.
